# Can I call `Channel.write()` in non-Netty thread?

Tags: java, netty

For some reason, I need write messages to channel(the operation is at server side, and the channel is already connected.) in non-netty thread. But I found that my client can't get the message though I got the success future. So how can I do this in right way?

And my netty version is 3.6.6-final.

Comment: There is no restriction to what thread you call `write` from. Especially on the client side it is regular practice to call it from your own thread, and I can attest from personal experience that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

channel.write() is thread safe so don't worry about that .

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Finally I got the message and I found it was going wrong because the bad string encoding method.